# Given a 3-connected graph, show that any 3 edges lie on a common cycle, unless the edges form an edge-cut

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let S be a set of three pairwise non adjacent edges in a 3-connected graph G. Show that there is a cycle in G containing all three edges of S unless S is an edge-cut of G.

Here's what I tried: I named my vertices $ab$, $cd$, and $ef$. I know that in a 3-connected graph, any 3 vertices lie on a common cycle. So I assumed that I could create the cycles $a-b-c$ and $d-e-f$ completely disjoint of each other (in which the paths $a-b$ and $e-f$ are the edges $ab$ and $ef$, respectively). [See image here.](https://ibb.co/CJRXc0C) Then, I showed with Fan Lemma, that there was a path from $\{a,b\}$ to $\{e,f\}$ that doesn't pass through $c$ or $d$. With that path, I could create a cycle... However, I was unable to prove my assumption that the $a-b-c$ and $d-e-f$ cycles were disjoint. Also, I suspect I was going down the wrong path.

Edit: Sorry, forgot to provide Fan Lemma. Consider a $k$-connected graph $G$, and vertex $u$, and set $V$ of $k$ vertices $v_1,...,v_k$. There are $k$-internally disjoint $u-V$ paths. In other words, for any $v_i\in V$, there is a path $u-v_i$ that does not pass through any of the same vertices as the corresponding $u-v_j$ for some other $(v_j\in V)\neq v_i$.

To elaborate, if, indeed, my assumption is true (although it may be false), then we know from the Fan Lemma that there are 3 disjoint paths from vertex $f$ to the set $\{c,d,a\}$. So, there's a path from $f$ to $a$ that does not pass through $c$ or $d$. In that case, we have our complete cycle. If the path, however, passes through $e$ or $b$, that's fine, since we just need a path from $\{e,f\}$ to $\{a,b\}$. [See image here](https://ibb.co/71h1BM9).... Again, even if we take the assumption to be true, this solution is also incomplete. What if our $f-a$ path passes through another vertex on the combined cycles, like a vertex on the $d-f$ path?

Comment: What is Fan's lemma? I can't find anything about it related to graph theory.

Comment: Call these edges $\{e_1, e_2, e_3 \}$, now consider the cycle $C$ in the graph which contains the maximal number of these. Perhaps this reduces it to some doable case analysis, (really only 2 cases to check).

Comment: @CalvinLin In context, it's almost certainly Dirac's fan lemma.