# What is the maximum number of distinct edges that can be contained in a cycle in a $k$-connected graph?

Tags: graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

I know the theorem below.

**Theorem.** (Dirac [1960]) If $G$ is a $k$-connected graph (with $k \geq 2$ ), and $S$ is a set of $k$ vertices in $G$, then $G$ has a cycle including $S$ in its vertex set.

What I am wondering is whether there is a similar result for $k$ edges. That is to say:

**Problem 1.** Let $G$ be a $k$-connected graph (with $k \geq 2$ ). If $S$ is an edge set in $G$, then what is the upper bound for $|S|$ to ensure that there exists a cycle in $G$ that includes $S$ in its edge set?

Through my research, I have discovered some properties for some special values of $k$.

- [Show any two edges in a 2-connected graph lie on a cycle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3005438/show-any-two-edges-in-a-2-connected-graph-lie-on-a-cycle)
- [Given a 3-connected graph, show that any 3 edges lie on a common cycle, unless the edges form an edge-cut](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3607222/given-a-3-connected-graph-show-that-any-3-edges-lie-on-a-common-cycle-unless-t)

Among them, I find the second statement interesting. It implies that the statement $|S| = k$ in the previous question  may not hold unless certain additional constraints are imposed.

---

In fact, we can ask a  related question as follows:

**Problem 2.** Given a $k$-connected graph, does any $k$ edges lie on a common cycle, unless the edges form an edge-cut?

If the above statement is negative, then can we provide a counterexample?

Comment: I think you should add the requirement that the edges are non adjacent (as in your second link), otherwise if you have three edges incident to a common vertex, no cycle can go through all

Comment: @caduk Yes, it is indeed necessary to include the conditions you mentioned.

Comment: I also suppose that as in dirac's theorem, we talk about vertex connectivity

Comment: @caduk Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **[Lovász–Woodall conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lov%C3%A1sz%E2%80%93Woodall_conjecture)** is essentially the same as this question. It says:

> If $G$ is a $k$-connected graph and $L$ is a set of $k$ independent edges in $G$, then $G$ has a cycle containing $L$, *unless* $k$ is odd and $L$ is an edge cut.

Note that we only want to avoid $L$ being an edge cut if $k$ is odd. That's because, if $L$ is an edge cut and we want to traverse all the edges in $L$, we will go from one side of the cut to the other $k$ times. If $k$ is odd, we will end up on a different side from where we started, and won't be able to finish the cycle. If $k$ is even, however, there is no problem.

As far as I can tell, the conjecture does not yet have a proof. Here are a few interesting results:

- In 1982, [Häggkvist and Thomassen](https://doi.org/10.1016/0012-365X(82)90078-4) proved that if $G$ is actually $(k+1)$-connected (but $L$ still has only $k$ edges) then $G$ has a cycle containing $L$.
- In 1985, [Péter Erdős and Győri](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01955745) proved the conjecture for $k=4$.
- In 1996, [Sanders](https://doi.org/10.1016/0012-365X(95)00079-C) proved the conjecture for $k=5$.
- In 2001, [Kawarabayashi](https://doi.org/10.1006/jctb.2001.2059) proved that under these conditions, $G$ either has a cycle containing $L$, or two disjoint cycles which together contain $L$. The paper claims to lead to the proof of the conjecture, and some later papers cite it that way, but I don't think this has panned out. It is still significant progress towards the conjecture!
- In 2019, [Knappe and Pitz](https://doi.org/10.1002/jgt.22497) proved that if $G$ has no odd cut of size at most $k$ (a slightly different condition from $G-L$ being connected) then $G$ has a *closed walk* through $k$ prescribed edges, which no longer have to be independent.

---

By the way, even though asking for the edges in $L$ to be independent is enough to avoid the obviously-impossible cases, it is not necessary. Another reasonable condition is to ask for $L$ to be a **linear forest**: that is, a forest in which all components are paths.

This version of the question appears more general, but in fact we can reduce it to the question with independent edges. Suppose that $G$ is a $k$-connected graph, $L$ is a $k$-edge linear forest in $G$, and $L$ has a path component with $\ell > 1$ edges in it. Then we can:

1. Delete the $\ell-1$ interior vertices of that path from $G$ (and delete the $\ell$ edges of the path from $L$).
2. Add an edge joining the remaining two vertices of the path to $G$ (if it is not already present) and to $L$.

The result is that $G$ is now only $(k-\ell+1)$-connected, but $L$ has only $k-\ell+1$ edges. Repeat on every component of $L$, and we end up in the case of the Lovász–Woodall conjecture.

The condition "if $k$ is odd, $L$ must not be an edge cut" changes slightly after we perform these transformations. The *final* result after all these steps are done must satisfy it. For the *original* linear forest $L$, the condition is:

> If the number of components of $L$ is odd, then deleting all edges and all degree-$2$ vertices of $L$ must not disconnect $G$.

This condition is necessary, for the same reason that the edge cut condition is necessary for the Lovász–Woodall conjecture.

Comment: Thanks. I noticed that in the progress you mentioned, the discussions were about whether some edges are in a **circuit**, rather than a **cycle**. I feel like there might be a distinction between the two concepts. I hope I didn't misunderstand. I checked the original reference (L. Lovfisz, Problem 5, Period. Math. Hungar. 4 (1974) 82.), but unfortunately, I couldn't find an electronic version of it. (may be in https://link.springer.com/journal/10998/volumes-and-issues)

Comment: Graph theory terminology wasn't particularly consistent at the time the early sources were written. Knappe and Pitz, who are more modern, use the word "cycle" when talking about all the previous results (and specify that they use the terminology of Bollobás's *Graph Theory* when they do so).